# How to properly delete data from json with python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Im trying to find the proper way to delete json data with python.
My goal with the python script is to remove the contact that the user inputs. I want to remove their email, number, and name but keep the rest of my contacts.

My json looks like this:

```
{
    "contacts": {
        "example_contact": {
            "email": "email@domain.com",
            "number": "phone number"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats desired output?

Comment: I would like to delete the whole contact. so the email and tag as well as the "example contact part "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the json to a `dict`, manipulate the `dict`, and turn it back to json.

```
In [244]: json_string = """{
     ...:     "contacts": {
     ...:         "example_contact": {
     ...:             "email": "email@domain.com",
     ...:             "number": "phone number"
     ...:         }
     ...:     }
     ...: }"""

In [250]: contacts = json.loads(json_string)

In [251]: del contacts['contacts']['example_contact']

In [252]: contacts
Out[252]: {'contacts': {}}

In [253]: json.dumps(contacts)
Out[253]: '{"contacts": {}}'
```