# How would i delete something from a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm not sure how to delete something from a .json file

I've tryed looking it up and it still nothing :(

```py
@bot.command()
async def afkremoveme(ctx):
#pls help me I'm lost!
```

no errors

Comment: Read the file into an object, modify the object, then write the object back to the file.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: in js simply use delete jsonObject.key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly delete data from json with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393270/how-to-properly-delete-data-from-json-with-python)

Comment: I need a line of code like an example...

Comment: plus that link isn't even discord.py

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want your command to do, but here's an example of how you would implement json into discord.py.

Here, whenever the command is executed, the bot opens a json file, reads the data, and sees if the message author is in the data. If the author is in the data, the key/value pair is deleted, and the data is rewritten into the json file:

```py
import json

@bot.command()
async def afkremoveme(ctx):

    f = "yourFile.json"
    author = str(ctx.author.id)

    with open(f, "r") as read_file:
        data = json.load(read_file)

    if author in data: # if any key in the dictionary is an integer, it is converted to a string when a json file is written

        del data[author]
        newData = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

        with open(f, "w") as write_file:
            write_file.write(newData)

        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.display_name} is no longer afk...")
```

This is reading a json file that looks like this (replace 000000 with your id):

```
{
    "000000" : "afk",
    "someOtherGuy" : "afk"
}
```

All of this uses dictionaries and the json module. If you're unfamiliar with either of the concepts, here are a few links to help you out :-)

[Python Dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp),
[Python-Json](https://realpython.com/python-json/)